# Javascript: condition of innerWidth not working

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to achieve different styling on different screen resolutions.

I've tried `if(window.innerWidth >= ) {}` but it's not working. Let's say I want the color of h1 to be blue when the screen resolution is smaller than 768px, the styling immediately changed even the width of the screen is bigger than the defined width.

See the code below:

```html
<h1 id="change" style="color: red;";>Hello</h1>

<script>

  if(window.innerWidth <= 768){
    document.getElementById("change").style.color = "blue";
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Maybe what you need is [media queries](https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-css-media-queries/)

Comment: @HaoWu I need to use the JavaScipt method because what I want to achieve is not styling instead of a script...This is just for illustration purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your snippet only gets run once on load.
You´d have to set this snippet in a loop so it gets tested again and again.
There is a EventListener called "resize" which you could use.

```
window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
        if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
            document.getElementById("change").style.color = "blue";
        }
});
```

Why dont you use css media queries?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use CSS media queries?!

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #change {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="change">This is a dummy text</p>
```